# BeautifulSoup - .string is empty

Tags: beautifulsoup

When I use `.string` with BeautifulSoup, it should be returning the text/content. But when I do it on an item like this below, it doesn't return anything. I'm trying to replace the string/text in theis html element, which requires to use `.string.replace_with()`. So simply using `item.text`, is not an option here. So how do I get this to return that content so I can do `.replace_with()`?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<p class="text">If you saw the movie "<em>The Devil's Advocate (1997)"</em>, perhaps you remember the end. Milton proposes to Kevin to take over his company, promising that he will have everything in the world, but with a single price - to sell his soul. But Kevin was hiding virtues that Milton did not believe that he has them.</p>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')    
item = soup.find('p', {'class':"text"})   

item.string
```

So If I do:

```
item.string.replace_with('Some TEST string')
```

I'll get an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace_with'` since `item.string` returns `None`

I'm expecting the output to be:

```
print(item)
<p class="text">Some TEST string</p>
```

Comment: What are you trying to replace? The tags or words in the string?

Comment: the content. So words in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple solution. You can simply set the string equal instead of using replace.

```
item.string = 'Some TEST string'
```